# Sharepoint online how to get site logo url in Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, site-collection

Is there any way to get site logo url in Sharepoint Online App (CSOM) ? I can't find any solution.

```
var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostUrl);
var web = hostcontext.get_web();
var logo = context.siteLogoUrl;
```

logo returning `undefined`. Can someone help me ?

Comment: you can directly get it from _spPageContextInfo.webLogoUrl

Answer (score 4):

Site logo url is exposed using the method `get_siteLogoUrl()`.

Try the below code:

```
var hostUrl = GetUrlKeyValue("SPHostUrl");
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostUrl);
var web = hostcontext.get_web();
context.load(web);
context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
          var logo= web.get_siteLogoUrl();
        },
                function (sender, args) {
                    console.log(args.get_message());
                });
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it was not worked. And tried some other solutions but still not achieve to work.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting `undefined` output. I read; "Site logo url is not reachable in CSOM". at the MSDN. So I pause to search solution for this problem.

Comment: Make sure that you have uploaded a custom logo to the host web. Sitelogourl is accessible using CSOM.The above code is tested in my app

Comment: Ok, I'll try to upload custom logo. I'll write result.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from `_spPageContextInfo`. No request is needed to the server using `context.executeQueryAsync()`. Just use following!!

```
var logo = _spPageContextInfo.webLogoUrl;
```